# check file extension in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jinja2

I am making a project using Django and using Jinja for template design.

Prelude:
I have a file in localhost server and I don't know what kind of file is it.
So, how do I choose tags in html to show that file type is `<img>` or `<video>`?
I have searched in web and found out that I should upload my videos in Youtube and 
insert the embedded url in html using  tag. But I don't want to do that.
I want to save files on my server.

Question:
Please provide me some Jinja logic or something else so that I can insert some conditions like:

```
if file is image: 
    use <img> tag
else:
    use <video> tag
```

Currently i am using these tags

```
<img class="img-rounded" src="{{ status.image.url}}" alt="My image" width=400/></a>
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="{{ status.image.url}}" type="video/mp4">
```

is there any way through which i can check {{status.image.url}} is a video or an image.  by the way image is a model field and it is a file don't get confused by it's name

Comment: Where is the file come from, it is static file or it's a model field?

Comment: i am using model fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Im not sure what sort of Data Structure is file in your example code provided, I'll assume its a string.
And in that case you could create a conditional html tag like this

```
{% if ( (".jpg" in status.image.url) or (".png" in status.image.url) ) %}
    <img src={{status.image.url}}></img>
{% else %}
    <video src={{status.image.url}}></video>         
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i am using it like this  image = models.FileField(upload_to="media/image",null=True, blank=True)

Comment: So your field is a string with the url, I suppose the same applies, but you could consider using field[-3:] to check for file extension if one is present on the url, can you give an example url?

Comment: could you please elaborate more , I am not getting it.Show it by a code. You could see my post to see what i am doing i have edited my post

Comment: sorry but your code is not working .giving me  this error "Could not parse the remainder: '(".jpg"' from '(".jpg"'.. if i removed the second condition then it's working fine but not both at a time

Comment: Missing a parenthesis, has been fixed